# Group Policies set in domain controller not applying to Client

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, domain-controller

I am developing some group policies on a windows domain controller (Win Server 2016), but after testing a rule (R1) being applied for the first time on my client machine (Win 10), I modified it and it did not update anymore.

Even trying `gpupdate /force` did not work to update R1 on the client.

Thinking there was caching going on, I removed R1 on the domain controller and created a new one with a different name (R2). After a (long) while of `gpupdate` manually, my client found out that R1 was not there anymore, but now it won't get R2 at all.

The application scope for R2 is correct, and even broadening to something which necessarily has to include my machine and my user will not be sufficient for my client to get the new R2 group policy. Launching `gpupdate /force` to get R2 brings no joy, and `gpresult /r` confirms that R2 is not applied.

Am i missing something here? Can anybody suggest a way to force Windows to refresh the group policies from the domain controller, or force it to invalidate its cache? Please note I would try to avoid to leave the domain as this feels like not a solution, since every other machine here that encounters the same issue would need to leave the domain and join again, and I am somewhat reluctant accept that since Windows tells me the client machine will lose all the preferences for the domain user.

Additional information requested: from the gpsvc.log I found this regarding my R2 policy:

```
Found file system path of:  <\\mydomain\SysVol\mydomain\Policies\{3890C0BE-2CD8-420C-92D8-83F279BC4EF6}>
GPSVC(588.5a8) 15:03:07:492 ProcessGPO(User):  Couldn't find the group policy template file <\\mydomain\SysVol\mydomain\Policies\{3890C0BE-2CD8-420C-92D8-83F279BC4EF6}\gpt.ini>, error = 0x3. DC: <machine>.mydomain
```

I guess there is a problem with the replication of this rule then? I wish to add that yesterday it was just silently failing, while now it returns something along this error when I run `gpupdate /force`

My rule was in a OU composed by Users, and it applied just to myself (and since it was not working, I then also added my computer to the scope, without success). The setting was a user policy to copy some files in my user folder.

UPDATE: As suggested, I created a new rule, R3 and deleted R2. Windows would still complain about the missing files in Sysvol from R2. I turned off the machine as I had to leave for a while. When I was back, R2 was gone, no error would appear anymore, but R3 still would not be applied to my machine through `gpupdate /force`.
gpsvc.log reports, for R3: `cannot be accessed/is disabled/or has no extensions` 
However I am in the security filter so I should have access.. right? Moreover, the rule is not empty and contains two settings to distribute two different files to users. Opening that path manually from Windows Explorer works, and I can read the files in there.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestion!

UPDATE 2: On the day after, the client "just accepted" the policy R3 which yesterday refused to take. I am quite convinced there is caching involved now, or some kind of (long) replication delay. As of the reason why R3 may not have been applied in the beginning, I think this was the reason: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2016/07/05/who-broke-my-user-gpos/ . I have solved the issue nicely described by this article, but it took up to one day for my Win10 client to get the updated policy, independently of me running `gpupdate /force`.
Thanks to everybody for the suggestions and the great input.

Comment: You need to include the results from the group policy environment debug logging.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2015/04/17/a-treatise-on-group-policy-troubleshootingnow-with-gpsvc-log-analysis/

Comment: Hi, please let us know what setting you set, and to what OU, an error in a GPO design will make it not apply. (like user setting in a gpo done to target computer account (without a loopback processing))

Comment: What is inside the OU where the GPO is linked? Users? Computers? What type of policy setting is it, a user policy or computer policy? Have you rebooted the computer since you changed the GPO?

Comment: Please run from a command prompt: gpresult /r
Check to see if your policy is listed under Applied Group Policy Objects.

Comment: I have provided some more information you have asked for. Please let me know if I have to provide more / something else. @Joe: My policy does not show in the applied policies.

Comment: @Funnisto From that computer, if you manually go there; \\mydomain\SysVol\mydomain\Policies\{3890C0BE-2CD8-420C-92D8-83F279BC4EF6}\gpt.ini does the file exist, and it open ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 That policy does not appear to exist in the Policies directory, for some reason.

Comment: @Funnisto Delete your GPO and recreate it then please, it's your problem

Comment: @yagmoth555 I did that, now I created R3 and applied it to me. gpupdate /force will not get this new rule, but I will keep getting the error message for R2 telling me the path is missing in Sysvol. gpupdate should not even try to get R2 anymore, but....

Comment: I have updated the current state in the post as my client now managed to get rid of R2, but still won't get R3.

Comment: On the day after, the client "just accepted" the policy R3 which yesterday refused to take. I am quite convinced there is caching involved now. As of the reason why R3 may not have been applied in the beginning, I think this was the reason: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2016/07/05/who-broke-my-user-gpos/ . I have solved the issue nicely described by this article, but it took one entire day for my Win10 client to get the updated policy.